# Regular expression["0-9"] issue in java

Tags: java, regex, string, file-io

I have a text file as follows:

---

```
Title
XYZ
Id name
1  abc
2  pqr
3  xyz
```

---

I need to read the content starting with the integer value and I used the regular expression as in the following code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
   FileInputStream file= new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\ap\\Downloads\\sample1.txt"); 
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
          while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if (line.startsWith("[0-9]")) {
                System.out.println("Line: "+line);
            }
           }
}
```

The above code can't detect the lines starting with integers. However, it works fine if single integer values are passed to `startsWith()` function.
Please suggest, where I went wrong.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you please suggest me the alternative solution?

Comment: Use methods that do interpret regular expressions. Take a look at the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes. Or for simple cases like this, check Rohit's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`String#startsWith(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method doesn't take regex. It takes a string literal.

To check the first character is digit or not, you can get the character at index 0 using [`String#charAt(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) method. And then test that character is digit or not using [`Character#isDigit(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) method:

```
if (Character.isDigit(line.charAt(0)) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For regex you can use the "matches" method, like this:

```
line.matches("^[0-9].*")
```

Comment: That only matches a single-character string. You want `^[0-9].*`

Comment: No. There's no such requirement. Please read the question again. "I need to read the content starting with the integer value"

Comment: Yes, your regex doesn't match all strings starting with an integer value, it matches strings which _consist entirely_ of a single-digit integer value.

Comment: Yes you are right, i thought he just wanted to make sure the line started with a int value (for this purpose we only need to get the first number). If he wants to get the actual number then he should do like you suggested. I'll edit, thanks.

Comment: Nope, still wrong. Neither of your regexes so far matches "a line starting with an integer". They both simply match "a line which **is** an integer", and so will return `false` for every line in the file. You need the `.*` afterwards to match the rest of the line.